# SVN two different repos

Tags: svn

We have our own repository and our client has their own, is there a way to somehow sync them but at the same time keep them separated?

Comment: You want to cross-copy all updates?

Comment: How can a repository be synced yet separate? Does not one imply the other?

Comment: it is complex i know, but we have read-only access to the client's repo and we need to supply patches, in order to test we need to commit our changes to our local repo and push to staging.

Answer (score 1):

Look into SVN externals, which permits you to checking a version of another repo into a subdirectory of your repo.  This maintains version control over the binding of your particular version to the specific checkin / tag / branch / head of the external repository.

It might be the solution, or at least a tool to build your solution.

Comment: I read something about externals but i would like to work directly within the directory rather than creating multiple subdirectories.

Comment: I can't see how you could combine different projects in one directory with guarantees that they don't step on each other (some project may eventually pick a file in another project's repository), so that's why the sub-directories are necessary.  On the bright side, if you combine directories your build system will likely become entangled with theirs, separate sub-directories allow for cleaner build chaining, leading to fewer hard-to-diagnose entanglements (not that they are guaranteed to happen).

Answer (score 0):

If you have two separate directories you could use Goodsync to synchronize the files periodically.

http://www.goodsync.com/